How has the PRC/CCP explained this statement by Mao about Taiwan?
Mao (1936, as quoted by Edgar Snow):

It is the immediate task of China to regain all our lost territories, not merely to defend our sovereignty south of the Great Wall. This means that Manchuria must be regained. We do not, however, include Korea, formerly a Chinese colony, but when we have re-established the independence of the lost territories of China, and if the Koreans wish to break away from the chains of Japanese imperialism, we will extend them our enthusiastic help in their struggle for independence. The same thing applies for Taiwan.

Here Mao seems to treat Taiwan and Korea on equal footing, with both being "equally independent" from China.
How does the PRC/CCP explain this? In particular, how do they reconcile this with such claims as the following?

Taiwan has always been an inalienable part of China’s territory [2022].


Taiwan has always been an inalienable part of China and has never been an independent country [2021].


Taiwan is NOT a country. It has always been an inalienable part of China. [2024]

(Do they for example say Mao's statement was a mistake or a slip of a tongue? Or maybe a mistranslation by the interpreter, which seems unlikely given how careful Mao was?)

This looks like a politics question, not a history question. In any case, (1) I don't know how you got independent from China in Mao's response, Mao was clearly saying that the priority was to get rid of the Japanese from the core regions first, then help other regions once the core has stabilised; (2) PRC hardly treats Mao's words as infalliable; (3) In 1936, presumably the 1931 constitution of the Chinese Soviet was still in effect, where even ethnic minorities had the right to form a new nation.

Its also quite true that the Taiwan of 1931 (prior to the ROC losing on the mainland and fleeing there) was a very different animal than the Taiwan of 1950+. But above all else, I don't understand the expectation that statements made by politicians are to be self-consistent for all time. Or that they even should be expected to. The given statements are nearly a century apart.

@totalMongot But how does this relate to history?

@totalMongot "in political words" how does this relate to history? Are historical sources/methods going to be more useful than political methods? or dialectic? or communist theory/ideology?  Why history?

@MCW Sorry I don't understand your comment. The question was about: why is there a lack of consistency between Mao's words and today's words, and how does the CCP explains that? The user TED answers more or less "no worries guy, politics say everything and its opposite". He also mentions that a century explains the difference but given the relative continuity, and the place of Mao in today's China, some consistency is expected. That's how it is related to history, and the reason for the quetion to be valid

Now history helps to explain: I agree that the change of WW2 and the fall of Mao created vast changes in the government of PRC, thus explaining that the political line about Taiwan could have changed without people finding it inconsistent

I suspect the CCP has never addressed this shift in any official way. Why would they?
To reframe this as an answerable question then, we might ask instead: when and why did their position change?
The origin of the so-called One China policy is usually traced to the Cairo Declaration of 1943, in which the Nationalists got the US and UK to agree that "all the territories Japan has stolen from the Chinese, such as Manchuria, Formosa, and The Pescadores, shall be restored to the Republic of China." The CCP position quickly changed. Once the KMT moved to Taiwan in 1949, that fundamentally changed the situation and raised the stakes so that this position would only become further entrenched over time.

There are several différences in the political path of Korea and Taiwan that led to current situation and claims. What is important is that some of those differences are consistent with Mao's declaration while still leading to a different outcome in today's politics.
Namely, the principal difference is that Korea was freed from Japan and offered political independence by Nationalist Chinese, Soviets and Americans. This resulted in a friendly regime and a less friendly regime in the point of view of communist China, both being recognized consistently with the Mao's speech you quote.
For Taiwan however, things were different: the population of Taiwan that was occupied was never asked about its political destiny, nor was proposed independence: it was taken under control by nationalist China in 1945 after Japan left, and then it was "re-occupied" when Chang-Kai-Chek had to consider leaving continental China to Taiwan: a brutal politic was undertaken by a governor to take control of the island and prepare for arrival of the nationalist. And eventually, after this separation in 1949, communist China attempt to conquer islands leading to Taiwan and failed. Thus, they were never the opportunity to consider independence. Moreover, Chang and Mao always agreed that Taiwan and PRC were a unique China, both thinking they would be able in the future to capture the other and unify China.
Thus, what Mao said is not lacking consistency compared to today's situation: PRC denies the existence of a Republic of China in Taiwan, with ethnic Chinese leaving there.
